# resttemplate getForObject map responsetype

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

***Update 02/05/2018 (about 4 years later)...I tested this again as people have been upvoting my question/answer and Sotirios Delimanolis is correct that I should not have to write the code in my answer to make this work. I used basically the same RestTemplate/REST service setup as shown in my question with the REST service having a confirmed response content type of application/json and RestTemplate was able to process the response with no issues into a Map.***

---

I'm invoking a rest service that returns `JSON` like this:

```
{
   "some.key" : "some value",
   "another.key" : "another value"
}
```

I would like to think that I can invoke this service with a `java.util.Map` as the response type but that's not working for me.  I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map]
```

Should I just specify `String` as the response type and convert the `JSON` to a `Map`?

**Edit I**

Here's my restTemplate call:

```
private Map<String, String> getBuildInfo(String buildUrl) {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(buildUrl, Map.class);
}
```

Here's how I'm setting up the restTemplate:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    interceptors.add(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            HttpRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
            requestWrapper.getHeaders().setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            return execution.execute(requestWrapper, body);
        }
    });
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
}
```

**Edit II**

Full error message:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map] and content type [application/octet-stream]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:239) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at idexx.ordering.services.AwsServersServiceImpl.getBuildInfo(AwsServersServiceImpl.java:96) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Is it valid to have a dot in the key name? I would think that would be somewhat confusing.

Comment: @EngineerDollery It's JSON, it's fine.

Comment: Can you show us how you create and use your `RestTemplate`?

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the full error message. Please do that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -- it's JSON, so it's valid, but it's still not fine. If you want to convert this to a javascript object and then use dot notation to access the object you'd be in a bit of a pickle.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm pretty sure Javascript is smart enough to handle this. In any case, the error message is unrelated to the value of the keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I had previously noted, your error message is showing us that you are receiving `application/octet-stream` as a `Content-Type`.

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

As such, Jackson's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` cannot parse the content (it's expecting `application/json`).

---

Original answer:

Assuming your HTTP response's `Content-Type` is `application/json` and you have have Jackson 1 or 2 on the classpath, a `RestTemplate` can deserialize JSON like you have into a `java.util.Map` just fine.

With the error you are getting, which you haven't shown in full, either you've registered custom `HttpMessageConverter` objects which overwrite the defaults ones, or you don't have Jackson on your classpath and the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` isn't registered (which would do the deserialization) or you aren't receiving `application/json`.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Please post the full stacktrace and full error message.

Comment: oops - forgot to post it...putting it up there now.

Comment: @ZackMacomber As you can see from the error message, the response doesn't have its `content-type` set to `application/json`. That's what you need to change. If your API doesn't return it, inject it like you do for the request.

Comment: Just to clarify, this means you can do this: ResponseEntity<? extends HashMap<String,Object>> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(restEndPoint, (Class<? extends HashMap<String,Object>>)HashMap.class)

Comment: Also, one more thing to check, because I was about to lose it, is if it's not working for a junit test, run through any special config you have for the junit context as well, if it's different from the primary config. ugh

Comment: In case it helps anyone, the exact Jackson 2 dependency you need is `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`. I don't know the coordinates for Jackson 1.

Answer (score 42):

**RestTemplate** has a method named **[exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-)** that takes an instance of **[ParameterizedTypeReference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html)** as parameter.

To make a GET request that returns a `java.util.Map`, just create an instance of an anonym class that inherits from ParameterizedTypeReference.

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>> responseType =
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
```

You can then invoke the exchange method:

```
RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get("http://example.com/foo")
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
Map<String, String> jsonDictionary = restTemplate.exchange(request, responseType).getBody();
```

Comment: This won't change anything. The HTTP response has a content type that the `RestTemplate` doesn't know how to process. The `RestTemplate` will never get to the point in handling where it can use your `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

Comment: why it has been up voted by people. I can't see it working?

Comment: It works fine. exchange method is able to handle ParameterizedTypeReference.

Comment: Checked here, still works fine with Map<String, Object>

Answer (score 14):

I think you can achieve what you're aiming for simply using the RestTemplate and specifying a JsonNode as the response type.

```
    ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = 
         restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, JsonNode.class);

    JsonNode map = response.getBody();

    String someValue = map.get("someValue").asText();
```

Comment: Next, you'll want this: [Faster XML Jackson: Remove double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28646572/86967)

Comment: This is pretty much the best way to do it, with the exception that you need to add the `accept: application/json` header and it's all good to go!

Answer (score 9):

***Update 02/05/2018 (about 4 years later)...I tested this again as people have been upvoting my question/answer and Sotirios Delimanolis is correct that I should not have to write the code in my answer to make this work. I used basically the same RestTemplate/REST service setup as shown in my question with the REST service having a confirmed response content type of application/json and RestTemplate was able to process the response with no issues into a Map.***

---

I ended up getting the contents as a `String` and then converting them to a `Map` like this:

```
String json = restTemplate.getForObject(buildUrl, String.class);
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    //convert JSON string to Map
   map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
} catch (Exception e) {
     logger.info("Exception converting {} to map", json, e);
}

return map;
```

Comment: This is redundant and unnecessary. You're creating and using an `ObjectMapper` almost exactly like the `RestTemplate` already should be doing.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, you should not need to write code to do this!

Comment: @Doug I accepted my own answer because it worked for me.  I've found many a time that I just need to get work done and move on.  I haven't tested Sotirios Delimanolis answer but I suspect he's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old, but just for other people that may visit this topic:
If you want to register some additional converters with RestTemplateBuilder you also have to explicitly register default ones

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateBuilder builder() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .defaultMessageConverters()
            .additionalMessageConverters(halMessageConverter());
}

private HttpMessageConverter halMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ResourceSupport.class);
    halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON));
    halConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return halConverter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked 100% for me

in client

```
Map<String, Object> mapRespuesta = new HashMap<>();
mapRespuesta.put("mensaje", "Process completed successfully");
mapRespuesta.put("idResponse", id);
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(mapRespuesta, HttpStatus.OK);
```

in which it makes the connection

```
ResponseEntity<Map> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, params, Map.class);
String id = result.getBody().get("idResponse").toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@GetMapping(value = "getSunny/{userId}")
    public Map<String,  SunnyVO> getSunny(@PathVariable int sunnyId) {
        
        Map<String,  SunnyVO> newObj = new HashMap<String, SunnyVO>();
        final String url = "http://localhost:8085/Sunny/getSunny/{sunnyId}";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        newObj = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class, sunnyId);
        return newObj;

    }
```

It is working for me ...