# Faster XML Jackson: Remove double quotes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json:

```
{"test":"example"}
```

I use the following code from Faster XML Jackson.

```
JsonParser jp = factory.createParser("{\"test\":\"example\"}");
json = mapper.readTree(jp);
System.out.println(json.get("test").toString());
```

It outputs:

```
"example"
```

Is there a setting in Jackson to remove the double quotes?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Well, what you obtain when you `.get("test")` is a `JsonNode` and it happens to be a `TextNode`; when you `.toString()` it, it will return the string representation of that `TextNode`, which is why you obtain that result.

What you want is to:

```
.get("test").textValue();
```

which will return the actual content of the JSON String itself (with everything unescaped and so on).

Note that this will return null if the `JsonNode` *is not* a `TextNode`.

Comment: And more generally, `JsonNode.toString()` should not be used for anything other than debugging or trouble-shooting: it is not (for example) appropriate for serialization. Instead. objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node) is the correct way, and handles all escaping/quoting aspects, using mapper configuration, possible indentation.

Comment: The correct method name is "getTextValue()". So this

...get("test").getTextValue()

will give you the string value without quotes.

Comment: If the value you want to retrieve is not of type `String`,  `textValue()` will return `null`. If the value type is `number`,  you could use `intValue()` or `longValue()` to get the value you want.

Answer (score 7):

Simple generic ternary to use the non-quoted text, otherwise keep the node intact.

```
node.isTextual() ? node.asText() : node
```

Comment: This worked. In the case that you want the node to be printed as a string with non-quoted text, the latter part of the ternary can be mapped to a string using `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node)`

Comment: The correct method name is "getTextValue()". So this

`...get("test").getTextValue()`

will give you the string value without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonValue.get("value").isString().stringValue()`

Also check null before calling in single line methods