# Jackson - Serialize type with @JsonValue to plain string without double quotes

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to find a generic way to serialize value objects that make use of `@JsonValue` to a plain string. In particular, I need to suppress the double quotes that Jackson creates. Example:

```
class Scratch
{
   public static class ValueType
   {
      @JsonValue
      private final String value;

      public ValueType( String value )
      {
         this.value = value;
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
   {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      ValueType valueType = new ValueType( "1234" );
      String plainValue = objectMapper.writeValueAsString( valueType );
      System.out.println( plainValue ); // prints '"1234"', should print '1234'
   }
}
```

Instead of `"1234"`, I want the variable `plainValue` to hold the plain value only, i.e. `1234`. Of course I could just strip the double quotes after the string was created, but I was hoping there could be a simple way to directly serialize the object to the required output?

Note that modifying `ValueType` is not an option, so for example I cannot add `@JsonRawValue`.

Comment: You mean you want to serialise `value` as an `int`?

Comment: No, it should still be a `String`.

Comment: Well, `1234` without the quotes is not a JSON string. It's a number.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that what I'm aiming for would not be valid JSON anymore. I was just hoping that there could be an approach similar to the ones given for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646572/faster-xml-jackson-remove-double-quotes), which work directly on the node tree. Using `1234` as an example was probably a bad idea, `ABC` could have made the intent more clear.

Comment: Just to give an idea where my requirement comes from: I've been using such value types inside other Java Beans that are (de-)serialized with Jackson. In this context, creating valid JSON is mandatory, so the double quotes for a field value have to be present.

But now I wanted to use the same value types (hence no modification to the existing ones should be made) as `@RequestParam` method parameters for Feign client interfaces. And in this context, the double quotes get in the way because they become part of the URL (e.g. `GET /third-party-service/elements?value="ABC"`).

Comment: @HeinBlöd You cannot expect a JSON library to generate invalid JSON. If it could, that would be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing isn't valid JSON. Strings are always quoted. If you want an `int` value in your JSON, you have to make it an `int` in the JSON object. Or, perhaps, you can get away with a custom serializer for `ValueType`, which does the conversion. But you'd be working against the system, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my comments above.