# Call a endpoint which return a HashMap with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, endpoint

I have a endpoint with the below signature

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> myMethod(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {...}`
```

And I want to make a call with RestTemplate for unit testing. How I can do that because in method `getForObject` I can't put a collection as a responseType.

Any ideea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resttemplate getForObject map responsetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208828/resttemplate-getforobject-map-responsetype)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean this this: "I can't put a collection as a responseType"? It is certainly possible to use a collection (or a Map) as a response type e.g. `restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Map.class).getBody()`, `restTemplate.getForObject(url, Map.class)`. Perhaps you have a stack trace you can show us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few different methods that all seem to work...

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class MyTests {

    @LocalServerPort private int port;
    @Autowired private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void healthCheck() {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/actuator/health";

    //  choose one of the following...
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> e = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,JsonNode.class);
        Map<String,Object> b = restTemplate.getForObject(url,Map.class);
        Map b = restTemplate.getForObject(url,Map.class);
        ResponseEntity<Map> e = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,Map.class);

        System.out.println("entity: "+e);
        System.out.println("body: "+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: For reasons I haven't discovered, `RANDOM_PORT` seems to work in *some* cases where `DEFINED_PORT` fails with `must be configured with a MockServletContext`

Comment: The most interesting hint I have found about problems I had with `DEFINED_PORT`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443572/86967

Comment: Notice: Convert a `Map` to a `String` for printing by addition: `""+mymap`.

Answer (score 1):

If the map contains objects that aren't simple strings or number classes, `getForEntity` and `getForObject` methods may not deserialize the mapped objects correctly using the untyped `Map.class` as the type.  In that case, use `ParameterizedTypeReference` as described in [How to get a generic map as a response from restTemplate exchange method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125416/how-to-get-a-generic-map-as-a-response-from-resttemplate-exchange-method).