# How to get a generic map as a response from restTemplate exchange method?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

We have a rest service that returns a byte array inside a map of type . While receiving the response if I use Map without the generics, the byte array data is converted to a String. Is it possible to send just the byte data from the server, if so how to retrieve  that data from the client using RestTemplate?

```
 ResponseEntity<Map<String, byte[]>> result result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8085/api/fetchContent?Id=" + contentId+"&userName=trump", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class, params);
```

The above code will give  a compilation issue as the return type is a  map.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html):

```java
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, byte[]>> responseType =
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, byte[]>>() {};

ResponseEntity<Map<String, byte[]>> responseEntity = 
        restTemplate.exchange("http://example.org", HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseType);
```